# Is it possible to create reusable and generic Specflow step definitions for multiple similar screens using page objects?

Tags: selenium, .net-core, bdd, specflow

I am working on an app with many similar datatable / CRUD screens. I use Selenium with page objects pattern to navigate in the app, and object mothers to create predefined test data especially for forms with many inputs.

While writing feature files, it occurred to me that the tests are so similar to each other and that it should be possible to generalize some common steps for the sake of reuse and DRYness. The DataTable page object was easy, since selectors are the same for all the pages. So I created a `DataTable` page object that has the necessary operations for filtering, selecting the rows etc. I used DI via Specflow's Context Injection mechanism.

Example:

```
Scenario: List and search Users
    When I type 'test@test.test' in filter
    Then I should only see items with 'email' = 'test@test.test'
```

And steps:

```
[Binding]
public class DataTableSteps
{
    private DataTable _page;
    public DataTableSteps(DataTable page) => _page = page;

    [When(@"I type '(.*)' in filter")]
    public void WhenITypeInFilter(string value) { 
        _page.FilterSearch (value);    
      }
    [Then(@"I should see items with '(.*)' = '(.*)'")]
    public void ThenIShouldSeeAListWhereContains(string column, string value)
    {
        _page.VisibleInTable(column, value).Should().BeTrue();
    }
}
```

The problem is, I can't find a good design when I try to make a common step class `WebFormSteps` that handles form data for filling in various inputs with different `WebForm` page objects. I want to do the following:

```
Scenario: Add User
    When I go to '/Users'
    When I create a 'validUser' Item  #'validUser' comes from the object mother
    Then 'validUser' should be added
```

And use the same steps and step definitions for, product for instance:

```
Scenario: Add Product
    When I go to '/Products'
    When I create a 'validProduct' Item
    Then 'validProduct' should be added
```

I thought of using interfaces or abstract classes and let `NewUserInputWebForm` page object and `UserMother` to implement these, however I could not find a way to inject the right concrete type at run time. (I considered to put the concrete object mothers to the related page objects, that would mean one less dependency to the step, but I couldn't justify to add an object mother to such an unrelated class, i.e. page object).

```
[Binding]
class WebFormSteps
{
    IWebFormObject formObject;
    IObjectMother objectMother;

    public WebFormSteps(IWebFormObject formObject, IObjectMother objectMother)
    {
        this.formObject = formObject;
        this.objectMother = objectMother;
    }

    [When(@"I create a '([^']*)' item")]
    public void WhenICreate(string exampleName)
    {
        form = objectMother.Create(exampleName);
        formObject.FillForm(form);
        formObject.Submit();
    }
}
```

One thing that came to my mind is to use a scoped hook and register interface with the right objects, however there will be an abundance of tags and hook methods in that case. Similarly, I can register the type at some other step, for instance `When I go to '/Users'` step, but it would complicate things more. Reflection may be used or type name can be specified in the step definition: `When I create a 'User' named 'validUser'`, but that would make the brittle tests to be even more brittle. Furthermore, tests would become too technical, not cucumber at all.

Is there a good way to achieve this? I am not even sure if such approach is good practice (including data table) because I was not able to find more than trivial examples on such usage. Should I stick to specialized steps like:

```
Scenario: Add User
    When I go to '/Users'
    When I create a user named 'validUser'
    Then 'validUser' should be added to users
```

Comment: You have really technical scenarios. With them you start to want to write generic steps as possible. But the intention behind BDD and Gherkin was never to write automation scripts, but to describe how the system should work.  We wrote some time ago a blog post about it here: https://specflow.org/2017/fit-for-purpose-gherkin/

Perhaps you get can some input from it, to make the Gherkins easier to understand for every stakeholder (and not only developers).

Comment: True, I guess I would need some adjustments on the step definitions, but the original premise holds.

Is the problem using so much parameters, boring with implementation details or something here?

By the way, great piece of software :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably Scenario Outline will help you

```
Scenario Outline: Add User
    When I go to <Page>
    When I create a user named <Username>
    Then <Username> should be added to users
Examples: 
| Page    | Username |
|"//Users"| "User1"  |
|"//Users"| "User2"  |
|"//Users"| "User3"  |
|"//Smth" | "User1"  |
|"//Smth" | "User2"  |
|"//Smth" | "User3"  |
|.........|..........|
```

Comment: The problem is that I want to reuse the same  step for a bunch of other screens than user, so I can write tests using this generic step.

Comment: What about this?

Comment: Well, the actual problem lies in the polymorphism of page objects and how to inject the right page object instance. Should I use a dictionary or something?

Comment: You can use dictionary of objects and select by your <page> string, yes

Comment: It's a good idea, I thought about that. Though I was looking for a more type-safe and object oriented approach. Maybe a more sophisticated DI container would do the trick. Thank you. Also, is what I want to achieve -reusing steps in this manner- good practice for tests?

Comment: Well I personally think, that everything, what allows you to write less and do more, is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify all of this using a table and a data transfer object representing values from that table:

```
When I create the following user:
    | Field      | Value |
    | Username   | test  |
    | First name | John  |
    | Last name  | Doe   |
```

The step definition will get a `Table` object. You can use the `CreateInstance<T>()` extension method in the `TechTalk.SpecFlow.Assist` namespace to map the table to an object where the "Field" column matches property names on the class:

```cs
[When(@"I create the following user:")]
public void WhenICreateTheFollowingUser(Table table)
{
    var user = table.CreateInstance<UserRow>();
    var userForm = new AddEditUserPageObject(driver);

    // Send user object to Selenium page object in order to enter
    // data into form fields
    userForm.FillForm(user);
}
```

The class mapped from the table would be:

```cs
public class UserRow
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

And a sample page object for Selenium:

```cs
public class AddEditUserPageObject
{
    private readonly IWebDriver driver;

    public AddEditUserPageObject(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void FillForm(UserRow data)
    {
        Username.SendKeys(data.Username);
        FirstName.SendKeys(data.FirstName);
        LastName.SendKeys(data.LastName);
    }
}
```

If you want to utilize an object mother in order to set some default parameters, you can do this using a different overload of the `table.CreateInstance<T>()` method that allows you to specify a lambda expression used to create a new instance of UserRow, which could then use the object mother:

```cs
[When(@"I create the following user:")]
public void WhenICreateTheFollowingUser(Table table)
{
    var user = table.CreateInstance<UserRow>(() => objectMother.CreateUser("someExample"));
    var userForm = new AddEditUserPageObject(driver);

    // Send user object to Selenium page object in order to enter
    // data into form fields
    userForm.FillForm(user);
}
```

And if you wanted to parameterize the value passed to the object mother you can always add a new step:

```cs
[When(@"I create a user named ""(.*)"":")]
public void WhenICreateTheFollowingUser(string username, Table table)
{
    var user = table.CreateInstance<UserRow>(() => objectMother.CreateUser(username));
    var userForm = new AddEditUserPageObject(driver);

    // Send user object to Selenium page object in order to enter
    // data into form fields
    userForm.FillForm(user);
}
```

And the step in your feature file would look like:

```
When I create a user named "test"
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I thought. Thank you. My problem is to find a way to simplify the 'Fill Form' step to "Given I am on 'Users' Page; When I Fill Form for 'aValidUser'; ..." So I can use the same step for all screens. That seems doable by using named instances for DI, or scoped bindings etc. I am more curious to see if that's good practice, say having tags for each object manipulated in feature, or not.

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş: I think you are trying to be too abstract. You will spend more time trying to wire up DI and create proper abstractions than you will just writing code specific to those use cases. Besides, when your scenario steps become too abstract, they lose business meaning. Scenarios should describe a typical business use case such that your end users or product owner can understand what is going on. Scenarios should be devoid of technical jargon. Abstraction in this case is detrimental.

Comment: Yeah, most of Internets seems to agree with you as well. I guess you are right Specflow/Cucumber is not fit for such kind of scenario. Then again, people are using them to write unit tests with.

Comment: @YamaçKurtuluş: Cucumber is a good fit for this kind of testing, but you need to keep the terminology focused on the use case and end user. A test is defined by the behavior it measures, not by the wording used in a step. You can still test the behavior with cucumber how you want to test it, but you still want your tests devoid of technical jargon, that's all. There's nothing wrong with writing unit tests in cucumber, as long as the steps and scenarios are written in business language, not technical language.

Comment: If in your particular case end user or other technically unskilled person wants to know what is going on in your tests, then you must provide it to them in understandable way. If not, then you can be abstract, why not?

Comment: @Somber: Even if you do not provide these tests to the business owner or end users, it is still useful for the engineering team for three reasons: 1) It allows the engineering team to associate business terminology with the technical implementation; 2) It serves as a form of documentation for how the application behaves; and most importantly; 3) They are real tests that pass or fail as the application evolves. A test fails, you either remove it, because it no longer applies, or change it to fit the new behavior. This forces you to update your documentation so the tests pass.