# Specflow: Replace Name(pass string from feature file) to AccessibilityId in step definition file

Tags: c#, specflow, winappdriver, feature-file

I am new to Specflow. My framework is with C#. 
Feature file:

```
Feature: test ABC app

Scenario: 00 Application is open 
    Given Application is open in "User" mode
    When the "Configuration" screen is open

Scenario: 02 Search for servers
    Given the "Add Server" screen is open
    And "Request Server" button is clicked
    When the "Request serer" screen is open
```

In the step definition file the function is like:

```
 [When(@"the ""(.*)"" screen is open")]
 [Given(@"the ""(.*)"" screen is open")]
 public void GivenScreenIsOpen(string element)
 {
   element_Interactions.ClickOnElement(element);
 }
```

Solution needed:
From the feature file, I am passing a string with a screen name as a variable but in the step definition file, instead of using **driver.FindElementByName(element)** i want to use **driver.FindElementByAccessibilityId(element)**. **I am not able to get a workaround on how to use/call AccessibilityId for the appropriate screen name from my page class in the step definition function and how to dynamically use same for all other screens**

thanks in advance.

Comment: I got a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58021071/is-it-possible-to-create-reusable-and-generic-specflow-step-definitions-for-mult/61189010#61189010

Comment: So does the element have a different accessibility Id on each screen?

Comment: @greg yes. On each screen I have different accessibility id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not 100% sure what you are dealing with, but it seems like a dictionary of screens and accessibility Ids would be the simplest solution:

```
[Binding]
public class YourSteps
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> accessibilityIds = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "screen1", "accessibility-id-"},
        { "screen2", "accessibility-id-2"},
        { "screen3", "accessibility-id-3"}
    };

    [When(@"the ""(.*)"" screen is open")]
    [Given(@"the ""(.*)"" screen is open")]
    public void GivenScreenIsOpen(string element)
    {
        var accessibilityId = accessbilityIds[element];

        // Or however you click on an element by its accessibility Id
        element_Interactions.ClickOnElement(accessibilityId);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is just that I wanted to create a common step definition file for multiple features or scenarios. Your suggested solution helped in one way. Thanks

Comment: @JavedKhan: Step definitions are global. They apply to all features. You cannot limit them to certain scenarios or feature files.

Comment: yes. I tried a few more things and understood what you are telling. Thanks for all suggestions and guidance.